# How to use Groovy's replaceFirst with closure?

Tags: regex, groovy, closures

I'm a newbie on Groovy and have a question about `replaceFirst` with closure.

The [groovy-jdk API doc](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/CharSequence.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.CharSequence,%20groovy.lang.Closure)) gives me examples of...

```
assert "hellO world" == "hello world".replaceFirst("(o)") { it[0].toUpperCase() } // first match
assert "hellO wOrld" == "hello world".replaceAll("(o)") { it[0].toUpperCase() }   // all matches

assert '1-FISH, two fish' == "one fish, two fish".replaceFirst(/([a-z]{3})\s([a-z]{4})/) { [one:1, two:2][it[1]] + '-' + it[2].toUpperCase() }
assert '1-FISH, 2-FISH' == "one fish, two fish".replaceAll(/([a-z]{3})\s([a-z]{4})/) { [one:1, two:2][it[1]] + '-' + it[2].toUpperCase() }
```

The first two examples are quite straightforward, but I can't understand the remaining ones.

First, what does `[one:1, two:2]` mean?
I even don't know the name of it to search.

Second, why is there a list of "it"?
The doc says replaceFirst()

> Replaces the first occurrence of a captured group by the result of a closure call on that text.

Doesn't "it" refer to "the first occurrence of a captured group"?

I would appreciate any tips and comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `[one:1, two:2]` is a Map:

```groovy
assert [one:1, two:2] instanceof java.util.Map
assert 1 == [one:1, two:2]['one']
assert 2 == [one:1, two:2]['two']
assert 1 == [one:1, two:2].get('one')
assert 2 == [one:1, two:2].get('two')
```

So, basically, the code inside the closure uses that map as a *lookup table* to replace `one` with  `1` and `two` with `2`.

Second, let's see how the [regex matcher works](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html):

> To find out how many groups are present in the expression, call the
>   groupCount method on a matcher object. The groupCount method returns
>   an int showing the number of capturing groups present in the matcher's
>   pattern. In this example, groupCount would return the number 4,
>   showing that the pattern contains 4 capturing groups.
>
> **There is also a special group, group 0, which always represents the entire expression. This group is not included in the total reported by
>   groupCount.** Groups beginning with (? are pure, non-capturing groups
>   that do not capture text and do not count towards the group total.

Drilling down to the regex stuff:

```
def m = 'one fish, two fish' =~ /([a-z]{3})\s([a-z]{4})/
assert m instanceof java.util.regex.Matcher
m.each { group ->
    println group
}
```

This yields:

```
[one fish, one, fish] // only this first match for "replaceFirst"
[two fish, two, fish]
```

So we can rewrite the code in a clearer way renaming `it` by `group` (`it` is simply the [default name of the argument in a single argument closure](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.es/2009/11/groovy-goodness-closure-arguments.html)):

```
assert '1-FISH, two fish' == "one fish, two fish".replaceFirst(/([a-z]{3})\s([a-z]{4})/) { group ->
    [one:1, two:2][group[1]] + '-' + group[2].toUpperCase() 
}
assert '1-FISH, 2-FISH' == "one fish, two fish".replaceAll(/([a-z]{3})\s([a-z]{4})/) { group ->
    [one:1, two:2][group[1]] + '-' + group[2].toUpperCase()
}
```